# Getting item from android listview on context menu selection

Tags: java, android, listview, contextmenu, android-spinner

I'm trying to update a item on my listview on a context menu selection, I had a listview with no spinner filter, and so i used:
int listPosition = info.position;
setorList.get(listPosition).getmMessage().toString();

with setorlist being my listview arraylist.

The problem now is that since i have the spinner filter the index of the item its giving me its not the item i select. I´m looking for a workaround , any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, the mistake i made was i was using a different list to filter, and was trying to get item of original listview, so now after changing the arraylist it works perfectly.

int listPosition = info.position;
setorList.get(listPosition).getmMessage().toString();

just switch setorlist with filteredlist.